# Can I buy some airports miles away from where Im based and get passengers wanted to go to them airports only

Tags: pocket-planes

In my game, I am based in Europe at the moment. Can I buy two airports in the US and have passengers just wanting to go to those airports? I know that I would have to buy cheap planes and locate them there.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Arqade!

Each plane has a certain distance they can go. For example, a Navigator-C has a distance of 690 miles, so it can fly 690 miles from your airport to another airport. If you are using Navigators, you would want to purchase an airport within 690 miles so that the plane could reach that destination.

- **How do I check how far my plane goes on the map?**
- First, **click the button on the far left with a plane and a green arrow**. Next, **click the button furthest right** (It also has a green arrow). You should see a circle around your plane. The plane will be able to fly anywhere within that circle. Below are some **screen shots of my plane's flying range**. I have also bought an airport outside of my range for answering purposes **(Miami)**.

[image: PlaneRange]

- Notice how my Navigator-C can fly to areas in the western United States and parts of Mexico, but cannot fly to Miami. This is the message you and I will get if we try to fly to a place that is too far away.

[image: Whyyounoletmefly]

- **In conclusion, you can buy airports that are really far away, but they serve no purpose unless you have a plane that can fly to that location.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can buy a pair of airports very far away, however:

1. You would have to take a plane out of the hanger there - you can't fly it there.
2. Those 2 airports will generate cargo/passengers for other airports that you won't be able to get out of that locale, so it will be very inefficient serving that area.